# Query Datatable to return alls rows for the same month

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a Datatable which I'm querying for values:

```
res = (from rows in dtInvoicesStamped.AsEnumerable()
       where rows.Field<string>("Centre Name") == col.Name &&
             (rows.Field<string>("Doc Type") == row.Name
       select rows).CopyToDataTable();
```

It works OK until I need to query it for the values of a specific month:

```
res = (from rows in dtInvoicesStamped.AsEnumerable()
       where rows.Field<string>("Centre Name") == col.Name &&
             (rows.Field<string>("Doc Type") == row.Name
             && rows.Field<DateTime>("Date Loaded") == period.Month)
       select rows).CopyToDataTable();
```

**Difference is in the 4 row of the above code

If I try to add the period, which is month, it returns me the error

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type DateTime and Int.

If I use only period, it will do ok, but obviously it won't return the data for the whole Month.

What am I missing here? What I need to do in order to add this additional condition to my datatable query?

Comment: You cant compare "1/1/2017 09:00:00" to 1 .. its right..  you have to extract the month out of the field to compare it to the month..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(rows.Field<DateTime>("Date Loaded")).Month == period.Month` instead

Comment: The stupidest overlooking. It worked as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly compare the datetime with month. Use `rows.Field<DateTime>("Date Loaded").Month` to compare with the month.

```
res = (from rows in dtInvoicesStamped.AsEnumerable()
       where rows.Field<string>("Centre Name") == col.Name &&
             (rows.Field<string>("Doc Type") == row.Name
             && rows.Field<DateTime>("Date Loaded").Month == period.Month)
       select rows).CopyToDataTable();
```